# wpautop and a specific tag

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox

I need to have a custom tag I made to NOT be surrounded in p blocks, but I don't want to turn it off completely.  [Here is my code](http://codepen.io/simcole/pen/NGeEOm?editors=110) I'm trying to add:

The HTML:

```
<hnav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Breakfast</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Same Day - Hot</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Same Day - Room Temp</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Entrees - Hot</a></li>
        <li><a href="jobs.html">Entrees - Room Temp</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Vegetarian - Hot</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Vegetarian - Room Temp</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Soups</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Salads</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Sandwiches</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Receptions</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Hoar Dourves</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Desserts</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Drinks</a></li>
        <li id="x" class="x"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a></li>
    </ul>
</hnav>
```

The CSS:

```
hnav {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

hnav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

hnav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

hnav ul li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

hnav ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #616161;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

hnav {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

hnav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

hnav ul li {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 430px) {
    hnav ul {
        display: block;
    }

    hnav {
        font-size: .8em;
    }
    hnav ul li {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
}
```

The hnav keeps getting surrounded by p's no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue recently and found [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-empty-paragraph-fix/) to be useful. I would port the code to a shortcode and use this to strip out paragraph tags which are generated by default.

```
add_shortcode("hnav", function($atts, $content)
{
    return "<hnav>$content</hnav>";
});

// https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-empty-paragraph-fix/
add_filter("the_content", function($content)
{
    //define your shortcodes to filter, '' filters all shortcodes
    $shortcodes = array('hnav');

    foreach ( $shortcodes as $shortcode ) {

        $array = array (
            '<p>[' . $shortcode => '[' .$shortcode,
            '<p>[/' . $shortcode => '[/' .$shortcode,
            $shortcode . ']</p>' => $shortcode . ']',
            $shortcode . ']<br />' => $shortcode . ']'
        );

        $content = strtr( $content, $array );
    }

    return $content;    
});
```